# How to interpret NRMSE (Normalised Root Mean Square Error) without comparing models?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, interpretation, goodness-of-fit, rms

I have fitted some robust mixed effects linear regression models (using robustlmm::rlmer in R).

I have calculated the normalised root mean square error (NRMSE) for these models but I want to make sure that I am interpreting this correctly.

The NRMSE for one model is 0.13 and for the other is 0.85 (the outcome variables are not in comparable units and I'm not comparing them to each other, I just want to know how well they fit the data).

Am I correct in thinking that an NRMSE of 0 means a perfect fit and an NRMSE of 1 means fit equivalent to a random model? So the model with NRMSE of 0.13 has a good fit and the one with an NRMSE of 0.85 has a pretty bad fit but still slightly better than random? Are there any rules of thumb about what kinds of NRMSE values are considered good/acceptable/poor?

(Sorry if this already has an answer somewhere; I did search the existing questions as it felt like it would have been asked before, but I couldn't find anything relevant!)

Comment: Did you ever find out an answer to this? @Mel